# Import "django.core.management" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, django

Import "django.core.management" could not be resolved from source

I am getting this error not able to clear it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5pU8.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pylance warning, not an error that usually appears in VScode because it's not detecting Django installed library. your application will work with that too.

Alternatively, you can try to reopen VScode or by creating a new virtual environment.